# Writing in json format

Tags: json, elasticsearch, splunk

I want to convert the following line into json to run it in elasticsearch sense plugin:

fields abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4

The above line is from a splunk search and is used to select specific fields.
I used the "match" keyword but it didn't work.

Comment: [Please, read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As far as you have asked, it seems you either havent done anything, or want something we cant understand what it is.

Comment: try using fields in elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using fields option

Allows to selectively load specific stored fields for each document represented by a search hit.

```
{
    "fields" : ["user", "postDate"],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-fields.html